# How can I say "yeah!" in Latin?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, latin-to-english-translation, interjection

A lot of songs, in English, have "yeah" in their lyrics. Is there an equivalent in Latin for that? Does Latin have some interjection or particle that could be used like "yeah!"?

Comment: I think that that English word has several meanings, and different ones will call for different translations in Latin. For example, there's the informal "yes" and expressions like "oh yeah". Are you interested in a specific song or context or meaning?

Comment: I believe it's more the meaning. Some songs start with "yeah! Yeah! Yeah!" Others have it in the middle "yeahhhhh!"

Answer (score 11, accepted):

One such interjection might be *Eia!* which [one online Latin dictionary](https://www.online-latin-dictionary.com/latin-english-dictionary.php?lemma=EIA100) shows as

> **eiă** *interjection. This word is an invariable part of speech*
>
> 1. (of joy) how now!, Ha, Good, see!
> 2. (of urgency or astonishment) see!, Quick!

Comment: This is really interesting because Portuguese has this interjection, as well. I never thought about it. I'm gonna check my latin-portuguese dictionaries. Thanks